# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown PHP link not opening

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dropdown menu, and it's used in a PHP page. I want that the main button (the one that has dropdown links) also still works and refers to a page. I did everything the Bootstrap page tells me to do, but for some reason it's still not working. (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns )

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="?action=landing">
        <i class="icon-info"></i>Information <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">dropdown #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dropdown #2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

That's the HTML, This is the JS I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var revapi;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()  
    });

    $('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click'); 
    });
</script>
```

How do I get the main button (Information) to link to "?action=landing" ?

Comment: @Kevin Pei : Not a duplicate as here, he still wants to show the dropdown list via hover event (as opposed to the accepted answer of the link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much frustration, I've managed to accomplish it by creating a `pseudo-link` and putting the dropdown menu on that.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwfNL/1/** 
**Javascript**

```
var revapi;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

});
$('.dropdown').hover(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle')
});
```

**CSS (necessary - to override bootstrap backdrop)**

```
#dropdown-link{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="dropdown-link" href="?action=landing"><i class="icon-info"></i>Information <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <a style="display:none;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @Rhendera no problem. What astounds me is that the original creators of bootstrap never considered this obvious usage case

Comment: I don't understand either, seems pretty darn obvious to me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Bootstrap prevents the default behaviour of href.

So you need to do it in jQuery :

```
jQuery("a.dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/?action=landing";
});
```

**EDIT**

It bugs because of this :

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click'); 
});
```

Replace it with

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).dropdown('toggle'); 
}, function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: While this works, it bugs out the dropdown menu (it looks like the click function keeps re-applying every 1 second or so) you can check it out at http://www.clients.amyranth.com/ (login with the password and username: test ) for a clearer example of what I mean.